# Selenium Htmlunit org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button, htmlunit-driver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YS6s.jpg)

Need support on issue selecting radio button, tried with javascript
but not working.

```
WebElement Select4 = driver.findElement(By.name("IsGoldMember"));
Select4.click();
```

Comment: Please provide complete, minimal reproducible case.

Comment: Selenium won't interact with elements that aren't visible. It was designed to interact with the page as a user would. Try clicking the LABEL instead. What else have you tried?

Comment: try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelectro("div fieldset.form-cbox--group div > input#IsGoldMemberTrue")).click();`

Comment: I've tried this, but it's still giving same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='IsGoldMemberTrue']"));`. It maybe the case that the name `IsGoldMember` is not unique on the web page.

Comment: Hey it worked with below code,                                                WebElement webElement= driver.findElement(By.id("IsGoldMemberFalse"));
      
      Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
         actions.click(webElement).build().perform();

Comment: The Html design on the application is not standard format which is creating issues I have above